# Is this a good practice to handle the displaying of the progress of data processing in a Class library?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection

I developed a C# class library, some of their methods shows information of its processing progress because they read and write millions of records, and the user asked for knowing how the process is going and the time they should wait.

Using dependency injection to avoid the "if console app write progress on console else if WPF app display progress bar",  (1) I have got the displaying on the console the time for every one million records processed if the method is invoked from a console application and (2) I have got the displaying a progress bar on a GUI if the method is invoked from a WPF application.

The question here is, is it a good practice what I am doing or, is there better/correct alternative to this matter?

My best regards.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Please don't do this.  If you are building a class library, you should make zero assumptions about the UI is interacting with the user.

Your solution sounds like it might work if you have a console window or a WPF application, but what if it's being called from a website or inside a service?  I've seen many a service get brought down beause some rogue class library was trying to display a dialog but there was nobody around to click OK.

The better solution is to simply raise an event whenever you want to report some progress, and let the consuming UI application worry how it wants to display that progress to the user.

See how the BackgroundWorker class works for a good model of this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xs8549b.aspx

Answer (score 5):

I wouldn't expect a class library to *display* the progress itself. I'd expect it provide hooks - probably in the form of events - so that whatever *using* the class library can display that information in the most appropriate form.

Quite how much control you want to give over that (e.g. report to me on every item or every N items) is a matter you'll have to work out for yourself - but it should be fairly easy for a handler to work that sort of thing out for itself.

Comment: This is a very good approach for most class libraries that process data. Especially if the amount of data is enormous.
*grovels* We are not worthy!!!

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Would it be acceptable for an overload (on the resource/time-intensive method) specifying that a progress window should be shown?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Unless the library is UI centric its almost never a good idea to include UI elements. As Mike Mooney said, what if the user wants to use the library in a ASP website?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: I don't think so, really. I think it would make more sense to *either* have that code in one central place in the UI itself, or if this is used in several UI projects have a separate *UI-focused* class library which knows how to do it.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: So, it could be done it two classes? One class that contains core functionality (without UI) and another helper class that provides UI support?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: The helper class shouldn't know anything about this *specific* functionality - it would be a general purpose helper to provide progress bars for features which needed them. The two should be *very* loosely coupled (and in different assemblies).

Comment: Perhaps a class that hooks into the already-defined progress events in the parent class?

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Well not really a "parent" class in an inheritance sense, but yes... and those hooks should be general purpose as far as possible.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: Right, really more of a main class.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example of raising events, this code will go in your class that is doing the work on the background thread.  The MessageEventsArgs derives from EventArgs (MessageEventArgs : EventArgs) so custom information can be passed to the caller.  This isn't required, one could use EventArgs e as well.

```
public delegate void SchemaProcessorMessageEventHandler(object sender, MessageEventArgs e);
public event SchemaProcessorMessageEventHandler SchemaProcessorMessage;


protected virtual void OnSchemaProcessorMessage(MessageEventArgs e)
{
    if (SchemaProcessorMessage != null)
    {
        SchemaProcessorMessage(this, e);
    }
}
```

Now in your caller (UI) set up the event listener.  Remove the event listener -= when finished.

```
_SchemaProcessor = new ServerSchemaUtilityFramework.SchemaProcessor();
_SchemaProcessor.SchemaProcessorMessage += new ServerSchemaUtilityFramework.SchemaProcessor.SchemaProcessorMessageEventHandler(sp_SchemaProcessorMessage);

void sp_SchemaProcessorMessage(object sender, ServerSchemaUtilityFramework.MessageEventArgs e)
{
    //Update the UI, if on background will need to (!this.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())     
}
```